# Trying to reference a variable before assignment inside a recursive function

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


def Count_Totals(lst):       # returns an array with the number of elements in each level on nesting
    for el in lst:
            if type(el)==list:
                    temp=el
                    index = index + 1       # this is index of Counts which indicates the level of nesting
                    Count_Totals(el)
            else:
                    Counts[index] = Counts[index] + 1               # When we reach the bottom nest to count elements
                    Size = Size + 1

                    if Size == len(temp) - 1:
                            index = index - 1 # When list inside list runs out of elements

in_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(in_file,'r') as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()            # reads entire ascii file and 
saves into a list called lines

Frame = 0
Size = 0
index = 0

for line in lines:                                # creates a list of each row in text file
        Counts = []
        Frame = Frame + 1
        Count_Totals(line)                       #Counts the elements in each level of nest

print("The Frame contains: %d subrames, which is %d Symbols", Count[0] , Count [1])
```

Hello, I am trying to write a python 2.7 program which takes in a text file that has nested lists and count the number of items in each level of list and outputs the values as a print statement. I have written the preceding code using recursion but I am having trouble running with the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment
```

My understanding is that the index inside the function is outside the scope of the index variable I initialized at the bottom. Any help to fix this code or get it up and running would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't want to access a local variable named `index`.  You want to access a global named `index`, which is what you initialized to `0` later on.

When python sees a variable used for the first time in a function, it has to figure out whether you intended it to be a global or a local.  It errs on the side of it being a local.  In particular, if you assign to the value, it assumes it is a local (the exact rules are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)).

To fix this, all you have to do is add a `global` statement into your function.  That tells Python that the specified variables are actually globals.

```
def Count_Totals(lst):
    global index
    for el in lst:
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, but just to clarify when I use a global variable in a function do I have to write global every time? Because now I am seeing the error: NameError: global name 'index' is not defined in the line                       Counts[index] = Counts[index] + 1

Comment: @AmmarAhmad I added a link to address that.  The rule is that if you assign to it, python assumes it's a local unless stated otherwise.  That being said, that error is strange.  I'd expect the error to be on `Counts`.  You should only need to state it once per function.